# How do you get recurring PaypalExpress payments to work with Active Merchant in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I'm using Active Merchant to try to implement recurring payments in the PaypalExpressCheckout module, but I keep on getting this error:

```
"message"=>"The token is invalid", "error_codes"=>"11502"
```

The token is being properly returned and set and now I'm speculating the problem maybe because the Active Merchant gem was not written for PaypalExpress to work with recurring payments, but after looking at the documentation there are methods included from the PaypalRecurringApi that can be used in the PaypalExpress module.

This is the relevant code that is causing the problem.

In my `paypal_subscriptions_controller.rb`:

```
        def create
            @subscription = PaypalSubscription.new(subscription_params)
            if @subscription.save
                if @subscription.subscribe_with_paypal
                    render "success"
                else
                    render "failure"
                end
            else
                render :new
            end
        end

        private
        def subscription_params
       params.require(:paypal_subscription).permit(:express_token,:payer_id,:email,:first_name,:last_name,:amount,:plan_id)
        end
```

And the relevant code in my model `PaypalSubscription.rb`:

```
   def express_token=(token)
      write_attribute(:express_token, token)
      if new_record? && !token.blank?
        details = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.details_for(token)
        self.email = details.params["email"]
        self.payer_id = details.payer_id
        self.profile_id = details.params["profile_id"]
        self.first_name = details.params["first_name"]
        self.last_name = details.params["last_name"]
        self.amount = details.params["amount"]
      end
    end

    def subscribe_with_paypal
        response = process_purchase
        Rails.logger.info response.inspect
        response.success?
    end

    def process_purchase
        EXPRESS_GATEWAY.recurring(amount, nil,{ 
            :ip => ip_address,
            :token => express_token, 
            :payer_id => payer_id,
            :period => "Month", 
            :frequency => 3, 
            :start_date => Time.now, 
            :description => "Checking recurring auto-renewal" 
        }) 
    end
```

If anyone could help me on this on that'd be great!  Thanks

Comment: Hi @Jamaal - Did you manage to get this issue fixed? I have the same error on my app.

Comment: Hey @randika I ended up not using ActiveMerchant for paypal recurring payments and found another gem that is much easier to use, check out this link: https://github.com/nov/paypal-express . The gem seems to be working well in development, but I haven't tested it in production.  Give it a shot if you can't get the ActiveMerchant thing to work and tell me how it goes

Comment: Thanks @jamaal I'll check that. Also I found this gem, seems does the job - https://github.com/fnando/paypal-recurring